# How to enable the animation on textview borders in Android

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-animation

I created an XML file that enables the textview border change colour on click. Now I want to add another feather that the border softly fades away. How can I do that?

Here's the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/textbox" />
            <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@drawable/border_pressed" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>    
    </item>    

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/textbox" />
            <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@drawable/border_unpressed" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your TextView in a FrameLayout, which has your background assigned to it.  Add an onClick listener to your TextView which animates the alpha of your FrameLayout's background Drawable in/out appropriately.  You may want to assign the background Drawable programatically to get a nice easy reference to it.

You will also need to forward touch DOWN and UP events on from your TextView to the FrameLayout to get it to change its colour, which means adding an onTouch listener to it as well.  I think the easiest way to facilitate the colour change would be to change `android:state_pressed` to `android:state_selected` and set selected on the FrameLayout to true on touch DOWN, false on touch UP.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you could just perform all of the FrameLayout stuff on the TextView itself - no need for two views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this by xml. Create a `FrameLayout` that has a `View` with the shadow as the first child and your `TextView` as the second one. Then use an `AlphaAnimation` to fade out or in your `View` with the shadow.